# How are reactive streams different from non blocking I/O?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

How are reactive streams different from non blocking I/O ? what is that java 8 future API cannot do that reactive streams can do?

Comment: Comparing 2 different sharks are Off-topic cuz it is **Primarily opinion-based**. The answer for this question is typically biased rather than pure facts and it is not helpful for the future reader.

Answer (score 0):

Same as non-blocking I/O, Reactive Extensions(ReactiveX) offers the non blocking programing style.

Not only that, ReactiveX makes everything as a stream, offers many operations for a stream. This functionality makes asynchronous programing very easy, saves us from callback hell ;)

I recommend you to read this document.
http://reactivex.io/intro.html

And here is good slide for ReactiveX.

1. https://speakerdeck.com/benjchristensen/applying-reactive-programming-with-rxjava-at-goto-chicago-2015
2. http://sssslide.com/speakerdeck.com/android10/the-mayans-lost-guide-to-rxjava-on-android

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is that ReactiveX provide some operators to run your pipeline asynchronously like **SubscribeOn** or **ObserverOn**. And also provide some other functionality that Java8 or Scala by default in his functional programing does not provide.

Here you can see an example about Asynchronous operators to understand how works https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java

And global examples of RxJava here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Answer (score -1):

Non-blocking I/O is a lower-level abstraction than reactive streams, who offer you constructs like these (consider serviceX to be a retrofit client):

```
Observable.zip(
  service1.getFoo(1),
  service2.doBar(xyz),
  service3.makeBaz("meh"),
  (a,b,c) -> service4.somethingElse(a+b+c)
)
.onErrorReturn("error");
```

This, in 7 contacts 3 services in parallel and when all of them have returned contacts a 4th with their results.

Comment: I am sorry I don't really understand the point you were trying to make..This can be achieved by a simple async library in javascript per say which spawns three routines in parallel and calls 4th one when they are done and all this done in a non-blocking way so I still dont see a difference between reactive streams and non-blocking I/O?

Comment: Zip operator does not run the observable asynchronous. Take a look to this examples to understand better https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/combining/ObservableZip.java

Comment: @Paul not by default. I my experience if you've set up your retrofit properly it will.